# MSBuild - Target for Visual Studio "start web debugging with IIS[Express]"

Tags: msbuild, csproj, msbuild-task

Is it possible to define a MSBuild target in .csproj file that targets the start of an IIS[Express] debug session?

I allready tried "BeforeBuild", "BeforeRebuild", "PrepareForRun", "BeforeCompile" but all of them won't run every time when clicking the start debug button in Visual Studio (ASP.NET MVC project). Build is only taking place if something changed for example.

I want to run a task only when debugging is started, but not on every [re]build.